# Keep option selected label in a select with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-select

i would like to keep option selected label.
I have the following select :

```
<select id="myselect">
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

So i have done the following code :

```
jQuery("#myselect").val();
```

But it return me 1, 2, or 3, in order to return me A,B, or C.
Unfortunately i can't change my select and the attr 'value'.

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to get the text A, B, C? Then you must use `.text()`

```
$('#myselect').text() //returns a,b,c
$('#myselect :selected').text() // return selected options text
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAdFc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
 alert(jQuery("#myselect option:selected").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery("#myselect option:selected").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want each option text at a time then use

```
alert($("#myselect >option").text());
```

and If you want selected option text then use

```
alert($("#myselect >option: selected ").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Solution:

```
$("#your_select_id option:selected").attr('label');
```